# ECサイトにおけるOGPのtypeの設定について

Tags: html

現在作成しているECサイトにOGP(Open Graph Protocol)を導入しようとしています。

商品一覧に使うのに適した`og:type`はなんなのでしょうか？
適切なtypeがわからないのでとりあえずarticleとして設定しています。

現在、トップページに`og:type website`をいれ、商品詳細のページには`product`をいれ、その他には`article`をいれています。

Answer (score 1):

現状の指定で良いと思います。もし商品一覧が何らかのカテゴライズされた内容であればproduct.groupを使ってもいいかもしれません。

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product.group/

articleは「記事」を示すものだと思いますので、もしブログやニュースなどの「明確に記事と言える内容」であればarticleを、そうでなければwebsiteでいいのかな、と思いました。

Comment: なるほど！ product.groupも今後、ジャンル分けをするようなことがあるときに参考になりそうです。articleに関しては、website指定はドメインのトップでのみ有効だという出所の怪しい情報を参考にしてしまっていました……調べたらそんなことはなさそうですね。ありがとうございます。